# Unity - PerlinNoise giving same number

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine, generated

I'm building a tile based game game where I want to generate a world for the player to explore. For some reason, Mathf.PerlinNoise() sometimes gives the same number over and over again, even if the XY given is different every time.

```
void Start () {
    treeOffsetX = Mathf.Round(Random.Range (10f,300000f));
    treeOffsetY = Mathf.Round(Random.Range (10f,300000f));
    waterOffsetX = Mathf.Round(Random.Range (10f,300000f));
    waterOffsetY = Mathf.Round(Random.Range (10f,300000f));
    boulderOffsetX = Mathf.Round(Random.Range (10f,300000f));
    boulderOffsetY = Mathf.Round(Random.Range (10f,300000f));

    for (float x = -gridX; x < gridX; x += 0.1f) 
    {
        for (float y = -gridY; y < gridY; y += 0.1f) {
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3 (x * 10, y * 10, 0);
            float perlinTree = Mathf.PerlinNoise ((x + treeOffsetX) / seedTreeX, (y + treeOffsetY) / seedTreeY);
            float perlinWater = Mathf.PerlinNoise ((x + waterOffsetX) / seedWaterX, (y + waterOffsetY) / seedWaterY);
            float perlinBoulder = Mathf.PerlinNoise ((x + boulderOffsetX) / seedBoulderX, (y + boulderOffsetY) / seedBoulderY);


            if (perlinWater > perlinThresholdWater) {
                GameObject waterTile = Instantiate (water, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            } else if (perlinBoulder > perlinThresholdBoulder) {
                GameObject grassTile = Instantiate (grass, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                GameObject boulderTile = Instantiate (boulder, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            } else if (perlinTree > perlinThresholdTree) {
                GameObject grassTile = Instantiate (grass, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                GameObject treeTile = Instantiate (tree, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            } else {
                GameObject grassTile = Instantiate (grass, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, sometimes the perlinTree or perlinBoulder will give the same number every time it will go trough the loop. Which will then output no trees or boulders. I have no problem with the water.

How is it possible for it to sometimes work and other times not work?

Comment: What are your threshold values?

Comment: Tree: 0.775, Boulder: 0.9, Water: 0.7